# Preserve property attributes (writeable, configurable) after JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say that I'm creating an object in somewhere else and passing it somehow to my module. Maybe it was created on the server in `node.js`, maybe it was created in a different module and for whatever reason I'm `JSON.stringify()`ing it and passing the serialized version (especially if its coming from the server). But I want this particular property to be immutable:

```
var foo = {};

Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
    value: 'bar',
    writeable: false,
    enumerable: true
});

console.log(foo.bar); //bar
foo.bar = 'foo';      //fails, throws err in strict
console.log(foo.bar); //still bar

var fii = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo));

console.log(fii.bar); //still bar
fii.bar = 'foo';      //succeeds      
console.log(fii.bar); //now foo
```

Is there any way of preserving this meta-data so that the `bar` property is immutable without sending it separately?

Comment: JSON is language-independent. This metadata is specific to Javascript.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Is there an alternate serialization technique that would have the desired effect besides sending the metadata separately and reconstructing it post-parse?

Comment: Nothing standard that I know of, you'll have to design a custom solution.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid it but I'll just write a custom `toString` and parser to handle it.

Comment: don't bother.. when foo is in a string format, any string manipulation can override / replace every configuration that you will make.. if you want to "protect" fii - simply call Object.defineProperty after JSON.parse

Comment: I was going to pass something like `'{writeable:false,configurable:false,enumerable:true}'` along with the other data to be passed as an argument to `Object.defineProperty` that way the object is still semi-responsible for its own integrity even when serialized and I can just make a function that splits the string on the other side and reconstitutes the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stringify the property descriptors, as in

```
// set up object to be serialized--from OP question
var foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
    value: 'bar',
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true
});

// create an object of property descriptors
var descriptors = {};
Object.keys(foo).forEach(function(key) {
    descriptors[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, key);
});

var json = JSON.stringify(descriptors);
// "{"bar":{"value":"bar","writable":false,"enumerable":true,"configurable":false}}"
```

Now, to reconstitute:

```
descriptors = JSON.parse(json);
foo = {};
Object.defineProperties(foo, descriptors);
```

Of course, this will not work with accessor-type descriptors which contain `get` and/or `set`, nested objects, etc. etc.

#### Using flags on keys

Another idea is to encode the writability into the keyname, via transformations on the way in and way out:

```
// Mark unwritable properties by changing keyname to 'prop:unwritable'.
function markImmutable(obj) {
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, p).writable) {
            obj[p + ':unwritable'] = obj[p];
            delete obj[p];
        }
    }
}
markImmutable(foo)
> Object {bar:unwritable: "bar"}
```

Then stringify that, and after parsing do a reverse transformation.