# Store in a file properly after using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

With that piece of code:

```
function item(name, number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

var item1 = new item('a',1);
var item2 = new item('b',2);
var box1 = [item1,item2];

console.log(box1);
var box2 = JSON.stringify((box1), null, 2);
console.log(JSON.parse(box2));
```

I get that output:

```
[ item { name: 'a', number: 1 }, item { name: 'b', number: 2 } ]
[ { name: 'a', number: 1 }, { name: 'b', number: 2 } ]
```

What I get with node is the same as the second line when trying to store `box1` in a file with `fs.writeFile(filePath, data,...);`.
Is there a way to get the first one into the json file ?

Comment: You mean keeping `item`? I don't think JSON have a way to remember classes, it only store data

Comment: yes the item, I know JSON does that, I was hoping for some alternative way.

Comment: I think the problem may be in how you write to the file, but you did not include that code in your question?

Comment: No.  The JSON format does not include the object type.  You'd have to invent your own storage format and create it and parse it yourself with your own code rather than use JSON functions.  The simplest thing to do might be to just add a property to your `item` objects such as `.type` and just let that property get saved with the standard JSON.  Then, when you read and parse the JSON, you can look at that property to decide what type of object to make.  That won't look exactly like what `console.log()` outputs, but it will get you the info you need.

Comment: Write a JavaScript file, then `require` it to get the data back. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161821/preserve-property-attributes-writeable-configurable-after-json-parse

Comment: thanks for your comments. but code in the long answer was exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **not automatically**. JSON won't automatically preserve the `prototype` of objects.

You *can* do it, but you'll have to handle it yourself with a little code.

---

**Longer answer w/ code**

In your first output `[ item {} ]`, the `item` is Node's way of telling you what the objects *prototype* is.

Unfortunately, that bit of information is going to get lost when you call `JSON.stringify` on the object, and all your `item`s are going to become plain objects. So when parsing them back in, Node doesn't know those `item`s are suppose to be created with `new item()` like they were originally.

One quick way of "preserving" the type would be add a new property into each object that "hints" at what the prototype is suppose to be, and handle that explicitly when parsing back in:

```
function item(name, number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;

    // prototype hint    
    this._prototype = "item";
}

var item1 = new item('a',1);
var item2 = new item('b',2);
var box1 = [item1,item2];

console.log(box1);
var box2 = JSON.stringify((box1), null, 2);

// now map over the items
var parsed = JSON.parse(box2);
var mapped = parsed.map(function(object) {
  if (object._prototype === "item") {
    return new item(object.name, object.number);
  }
  return object;
});
console.log(mapped);
```

If you need something more powerful, you could expand on this idea by adding `toJSON` and `fromJSON` methods to your `item` class, and then calling those methods when mapping to<->from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing your own serializer, no. Fortunately, a simple JSON serialized isn't hard to write, though the parser you'd have to write for using a nonstandard JSON format is going to be frustrating.

But, I suspect this is a case where you don't actually want. JSON is a language agnostic data serialization format. It stores data which can be represented in the form natural to the language. In Javascript, this is usually object literals. In Java or.NET it would be classes (POJOs/POCOs). In other languages, Maps or Dictionaries. Including name of your object's prototype with the object binds your data to a particular implementation which is likely to change. Suddenly, you can't even rename the item function. That's limitation you don't need.